# SQL Query Union with left join

Tags: sql, select, join

i have one table (TableA) with some data and a foreign key to TableB

```
TableA
 --------------------
| ID  | Name  | FK   |
 --------------------
   0     A      1
   1     B      3
   2     C      1
   3     D      2
   4     E      4
  ...

TableB
 ----------------
| PK  | Status  | 
 ----------------
   1    A21   
   2    A22   
   3    A23   
   4    A24
```

Now i want to Count how many entries in TableA have which Status from TableB... No problem so far:

```
SELECT Count(TableA.FK) AS COUNTA, TableB.Status AS Status
    FROM TableB
LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableB.PK = TableA.FK
    GROUP BY TableB.Status, TableB.PK;
```

Output:

```
 ------------------
| COUNTA  | Status | 
 ------------------
   2        A21   
   1        A22   
   1        A23   
   1        A24
```

Now ive got 3rd Table (TableC) with the same structure as TableA but different data.

```
TableC
 --------------------
| ID  | Name  | FK   |
 --------------------
   0     Ab      4
   1     Bb      3
   2     Cb      4
   3     Db      1
   4     Eb      1
  ...
```

i want now count TableA and TableC and output it in one table:

ex:

```
 -----------------------------
| COUNTA  | Status | COUNTC  |
 -----------------------------
   2        A21        2 
   1        A22        0
   1        A23        1
   1        A24        2
```

this is what i have so far:

```
SELECT        SELECT Count(TableA.FK) AS COUNTA, TableB.Status AS Status, Count(TableC.FK) AS COUNTC
FROM            ((TableB LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         TableA ON TableB.PK = TableA.FK) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC ON TableB.PK = TableC.FK)
GROUP BY TableB.Status, TableB.PK;
```

Output is not correct, CountC ist the same as Count A :(

Comment: General GROUP BY tip. The columns listed in the group by clause should be all columns from the select list except those that are arguments to set functions! (And the same order makes it easier to read.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a correlated query to your first query to get the desired result like this:

```
SELECT Count(TableA.FK) AS COUNTA,
       TableB.Status AS Status,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableC where TableC.FK = TableB.PK) as COUNTB
FROM TableB
LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableB.PK = TableA.FK
GROUP BY TableB.Status, TableB.PK;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select TempA.COUNTA , TempA.Status ,TempB.COUNTC from 
( SELECT Count(TableA.FK) AS COUNTA,TableB.Status AS Status ,TableA.FK as PK
     FROM TableB LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableB.PK = TableA.FK
 GROUP BY TableB.Status, TableB.PK) as TempA
 LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT Count(TableC.FK) AS COUNTC,TableA.FK as PK
     FROM TableC LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableC.PK = TableA.FK
 GROUP BY TableA.FK)  as TempB
 ON TempA.PK = TempB.PK)
```